# Implementing IEnumerator<T> for Fixed Arrays

Tags: c#, fixed, unsafe, ienumerator

I need to implement a **mutable** polygon that behaves like a struct, that it is copied by value and changes to the copy have no side effects on the original.

Consider my attempt at writing a `struct` for such a type:

```csharp
public unsafe struct Polygon : IEnumerable<System.Drawing.PointF>
{
    private int points;
    private fixed float xPoints[64];
    private fixed float yPoints[64];

    public PointF this[int i]
    {
        get => new PointF(xPoints[i], yPoints[i]);
        set
        {
            xPoints[i] = value.X;
            yPoints[i] = value.Y;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<PointF> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new PolygonEnumerator(ref this);
    }
}
```

I have a requirement that a `Polygon` must be copied by value so it is a `struct`.
(*Rationale: Modifying a copy shouldn't have side effects on the original.*)

I would also like it to implement `IEnumerable<PointF>`.
(*Rationale: Being able to write `for (PointF p in poly)`*)

As far as I am aware, C# does not allow you to override the copy/assignment behaviour for value types. If that *is* possible then there's the "low hanging fruit" that would answer my question.

My approach to implementing the copy-by-value behaviour of `Polygon` is to use `unsafe` and fixed arrays to allow a polygon to store up to 64 points in the struct itself, which prevents the polygon from being indirectly modified through its copies.

I am running into a problem when I go to implement `PolygonEnumerator : IEnumerator<PointF>` though.
Another requirement (*wishful thinking*) is that the enumerator will return `PointF` values that match the `Polygon`'s fixed arrays, even if those points are modified during iteration.
(*Rationale: Iterating over arrays works like this, so this polygon should behave in line with the user's expectations.*)

```csharp
public class PolygonEnumerator : IEnumerator<PointF>
{
    private int position = -1;

    private ??? poly;

    public PolygonEnumerator(ref Polygon p)
    {
        // I know I need the ref keyword to ensure that the Polygon
        // passed into the constructor is not a copy
        // However, the class can't have a struct reference as a field

        poly = ???;
    }

    public PointF Current => poly[position]; 

    // the rest of the IEnumerator implementation seems straightforward to me

}
```

**What can I do to implement the `PolygonEnumerator` class according to my requirements?**

It seems to me that I can't store a reference to the original polygon, so I have to make a copy of its points into the enumerator itself; But that means changes to the original polygon can't be visited by the enumerator!

I am completely OK with an answer that says "It's impossible".

Maybe I've dug a hole for myself here while missing a useful language feature or conventional solution to the original problem.

Comment: I suspect you want an immutable class, not a struct.

Comment: @DourHighArch, That may be a valid approach I will consider, but I do like the idea of being able to add / remove  points to a polygon "instance". I'm actually implementing `IList<PointF>` to modify those fixed arrays.

Comment: `Polygon` should not be a `struct` because `( 64 + 64 ) * sizeof(float)` is **512 bytes**. That means every value-copy operation will require a copy of 512 bytes. The .NET Framework on x64 does not guarantee that large object copies will be efficient (e.g. using AVX operations).

Comment: This seems to be a terrible inefficient way to do this and over engineered, why not use an array of points?

Comment: @FilipCordas, How would you allow `Poly b = a; b[0] = new PointF()` to be possible but also prevent that usage from affecting `a`?

Comment: @Romen Your `struct Polygon` type defines only a read-only indexer, not a read/write indexer, so `b[0] = ...` will fail because the indexer cannot be assigned to.

Comment: @Dai, Sorry I left that out for brevity. The setter is actually necessary but I didn't realize how relevant it would be to the question till now.

Comment: This is a bad idea in so many ways.

Comment: @EricLippert, Which is why I'm asking! I already felt that what I came up with was a bad design, I asked this question because I knew people would tell me specifically *how* the design was bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Polygon` type should not be a `struct` because `( 64 + 64 ) * sizeof(float) == 512 bytes`. That means every value-copy operation will require a copy of 512 bytes - which is very inefficient (not least because of [locality-of-reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) which strongly favours the use objects that exist in a single location in memory).

> I have a requirement that a Polygon must be copied by value so it is a struct.
>   (Rationale: Modifying a copy shouldn't have side effects on the original.)

Your "requirement" is wrong. Instead define an immutable class with an explicit copy operation - and/or use a mutable "builder" object for efficient construction of large objects.

> I would also like it to implement `IEnumerable<PointF>`.
>   (Rationale: Being able to write for (PointF p in poly))

That's fine - but you hardly ever need to implement `IEnumerator<T>` directly yourself because C# can do it for you when using `yield return` (and the generated CIL is very optimized!).

> My approach to implementing the copy-by-value behaviour of Polygon is to use unsafe and fixed arrays to allow a polygon to store up to 64 points in the struct itself, which prevents the polygon from being indirectly modified through its copies.

This is not how C# should be written. `unsafe` should be avoided wherever possible (because it breaks the CLR's built-in guarantees and safeguards).

> Another requirement (wishful thinking) is that the enumerator will return PointF values that match the Polygon's fixed arrays, even if those points are modified during iteration.
>   (Rationale: Iterating over arrays works like this, so this polygon should behave in line with the user's expectations.)

Who are your users/consumers in this case? If you're so concerned about not breaking user's expectations then you shouldn't use `unsafe`!

Consider this approach instead:

(**Update:** I just realised that the `class Polygon` I defined below is essentially just a trivial wrapper around `ImmutableList<T>` - so you don't even need `class Polygon`, so just use `ImmutableList<Point>` instead)

```
public struct Point
{
    public Point( Single x, Single y )
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    public Single X { get; }
    public Single Y { get; }

    // TODO: Implement IEquatable<Point>
}

public class Polygon : IEnumerable<Point>
{
    private readonly ImmutableList<Point> points;

    public Point this[int i] => this.points[i];

    public Int32 Count => this.points[i];

    public Polygon()
    {
        this.points = new ImmutableList<Point>();
    }

    private Polygon( ImmutableList<Point> points )
    {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public IEnumerator<PointF> GetEnumerator()
    {
        //return Enumerable.Range( 0, this.points ).Select( i => this[i] );
        return this.points.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Polygon AddPoint( Single x, Single y ) => this.AddPoint( new Point( x, y ) );

    public Polygon AddPoint( Point p )
    {
        ImmutableList<Point> nextList = this.points.Add( p );
        return new Polygon( points: nextList );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a single good reason to create this class, index should never create a new object in c# because this is not expected. A simple array or even better a span is much better.

Comment: @FilipCordas The OP is using `System.Drawing.PointF` which strongly hints they're not targeting .NET Core and so cannot efficiently use `Span<T>`.

Comment: Thank you for challenging my "requirements", but the one **actual** requirement I can't forgo is that the polygon type must be mutable. You should be able to add and remove points, and overwrite points through the indexer.

Comment: Nice! Forward iteration to the `ImmutableList`, of course.

Comment: @Romen Mutability and structs just don't work together (because of struct's value-copy semantics), that's why `ValueTuple` is not immutable for example. It sounds like you haven't fully though-out what your `Polygon` class should actually do. I think you really need two types: a mutable `class PolygonBuilder`  and a `class ImmutablePolygon`.

Comment: @Dai Ok didn't see that I was thinking this was a custom struct they made.

Comment: Could you humour my craziness for a second and tell me whether it is even *possible* to implement an enumerator for an unsafe fixed array such that you'll see changes to the fixed array as you iterate over it?

Comment: @Romen Well in modern c# you can still change a with b if you use ref A b = ref a; sound a bit silly to worry about something that can easily be done. I can see why your Poligon might need to mutate but then add a duplicate method and make everything a whole lot simpler.

Comment: @Romen Technically, yes - it is possible, but you shouldn't implement it because it's very difficult to do it correctly (it won't be thread-safe without adding locks, for example) and the majority of the .NET ecosystem today *expects* `foreach`/`IEnumerator<T>` to work in a consistent manner - that's why `List<T>` will throw an exception if it detects the list is mutated while the list is being iterated-over - and it's why `ConcurrentDictionary` and `ConcurrentBag` iterate over immutable snapshots instead of their mutable state.

Comment: @Romen a Poligon seams like something that should exist in framework or nuget, I am extremely skeptical about you actually having a need to write this class and not use something already out there.

Comment: @FilipCordas, I asked this question *because* I could smell that I was going in the wrong direction. The actual code doesn't really use such a simple polygon, that's just the core concept I needed to demonstrate the problem of having a struct with fixed arrays and an enumerator.